# Change iOS status bar text color while dark mode is activated

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ios13

With iOS 13 new dark mode feature, it now seems impossible for me to control the status bar text color in Xamarin Forms. Most of the solutions I find seem to be from before dark mode was introduced to iOS.

My application uses resources so that I can easily change the style of the whole app. Even in dark mode, the color of my navigation  bar is not pleasant to read with white text. I need to set the color of the status bar to black, **no matter** what color mode the device has activated.

I've tried to set the colors manually in my navigation page, but it seems to be overriden by iOS color mode. This code works on Android:

```
        BarTextColor = Color.Black;
        BarBackgroundColor = (Color)App.Instance.Resources["PrimaryColor"];
```

I've tried setting true and false to `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`.
I've also tried all settings of `Status Bar Style` in `Info.plist`.

Does anyone know of a way to control this in Xamarin Forms since the release of Dark Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by switching to Xamarin iOS SDK 13, it adds an item to the StatusBarStyle enumeration.

More info [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/403893#Comment_403893).

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this docs? [NavigationPage Bar Translucency on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/navigation-bar-translucent) [NavigationPage Bar Text Color Mode on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/status-bar-text-color) . Maybe translucency can solve your problem?